# Redirected to another php page from imagestring

Tags: php

I wish that when you click on the imagestring to be redirected to another php page.
I tried with php function `Header("Location: ./next_page.php")`, but I could not get a link.

```
<?php
 $width = 1100;
 $height = 1620;

 $im = imagecreate($width, $height); 
 $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
 $red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
 $blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

 $string='Header("Location: ./next_page.php")'; 

 imagestring($im, 3, $x1+25, $y1+58, $string, $red);       
 imagepng($im,"demoimage.png");
?>
<img src="demoimage.png">
```

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. What do you mean by "when you click on the imagestring"? What is an "imagestring"? Do you mean "when you click on the image"? Do you simply want the image to be a link that can be clicked?

Comment: Or are you looking for a way to have some string shown inside an image to act as a link? In that case take a look at an "image map" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map) or you place the string _over_ the image, not inside, so that you can use a normal anchor for it.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to briefly explain.
Yes I want the image to be a link that can be clicked, but image that is created through the imagestring function.

Comment: Then simply place the image inside a link (anchor) element: `<a href="target.php"><img src="demoimage.png" title="demo" alt="demoimage"></a>`. It is the link (the anchor) that makes its content clickable. It is irrelevant what you palce inside, text or an image.

Comment: Thanks arkascha. I'l try.